# A non-RAID Intel hard drive is not displayed as a Win10 installation option in HP Notebook laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a brand new HP laptop that I just took out of the box. When I booted it, it took me right to freeDoS command prompt. It doesn't come with windows, so I entered the BIOS to get some information that might help installing Windows 10:

- product name: HP Laptop 15-dw3xxx
- system family: HP notebook
- product number: 31Y40EA#BH5
- processor type: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7
- bios vendor: Insyde
- Bios revision: F.33
- Factory installed OS: non-Windows

I have used Rufus to create a bootable Win10 pen drive. When I boot the laptop from the USB it says there's no hard drive to install the OS on and I should find the drives manually. When I go to command prompt and use `diskpart`, I can't see the hard drive at all. Also, it's not shown as a boot option in the boot menu. However, I have a UEFI HII configuration option in the BIOS, it shows that there's a non-RAID intel PCIe 1.0 SK hynix BC511 hard drive.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You realise an OEM Windows would have added a couple of $£€ to the price. Buying your own will add 100 or so… i'd rethink your purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I need to go to [HP support](https://support.hp.com/us-en) and provide the product number, then install the suitable storage driver. A `.exe` file is downloaded then I need to extract a folder called F6 from that. Next, I need to paste it into the bootable USB and direct the wizard towards the F6 folder.